# Blank white page appears at the time of navigation in MAF app?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

In my app, I am doing navigation using springboard features link and by creating task-flows. Navigation is working good but a blank white page appears for some seconds and page shows with some flick-rings when redirecting. Is there any way to get rid of this annoying thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing worked for me was changing theme. I just changed theme name to mobile fuision and now there is no white screen.